# Limits for integral over ellipse

Tags: integration, limits, conic-sections

How do I find the limits when trying to integrate over an ellipse?
(1) $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$

Edit: I'm trying to find the area of the part of the plane $Ax + By +Cz = D$ lying inside the elliptical cylinder (1). 
I tried using parameterization for the plane to get the $ r(u,v)$ = u**i** + v**j** + $\frac{(D-Au-Bv)}{C}$ **k** with the normal **n**(u,v) = $\frac{A}{C}$**i** + $\frac{B}{C}$**j** + **k**.

Comment: Parametrization

Answer (score 1):

The area of the intersection between plane and cylinder is the area of the ellipse on plane $xy$ divided by $\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the inclination of the given plane with respect to plane $xy$:

$$
A={\pi ab\over\cos\theta}=\pi ab{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}\over C}.
$$

The figure below shows how the second ellipse is a dilation of the first one, by a factor $1/\cos\theta$, along a direction perpendicular to the intersection between the planes (green line).

[image]